# How to set different security levels with Spring

Tags: spring, security, parameters

I use Spring for my web application.
I defined a filter in my web.xml to redirect to the authentication tool of my company.

My web application is also accessible from an SWT application where the user is already logged in. So when he starts the web application, he should not have to login again.

How can I do this ? I tried with a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/fromSWT*").permitAll();
   }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Perhaps your SWT application can authenticate with your web app via some kind of token. At /fromSWT, there could be a filter that looks for this token in your request and if found, checks a database that stores these tokens to make sure it's valid.